# Performing prediction in sklearn on pickled data

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm trying to learn by experimenting on the newsgroup20 data set. My training model works fine, The prediction part is where i have a problem with. Now what I'm trying to do is save the training model(using pickle) in one function and performing prediction on the pickled data in an other function. All tutorials i find give me how to save and load pickle files but not how to extract X_train and y_train. Would be greatful if anyone could help. Here's my code

```
def classifier(): 
    twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', shuffle=True, random_state=42)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(twenty_train.data, twenty_train.target, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

    naive_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                         ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                         ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
    ])
    naive_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)  
    filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
    pickle.dump(naive_clf, open(filename, 'wb'))


def predictions(): # need help in first 3 lines and last print statement

    loaded_model = pickle.load(open('finalized_model.sav', 'rb'))
    result = loaded_model.score(X_test, y_test)
    print(result)

    #parsing my file as string for prediction(works fine)
    with open("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/text_classifier/dataset/predict/file,txt", "r") as myfile:
        file=myfile.readlines()
        file = ''.join(file)

    print('belongs to class {} according to naive bayes'.format(twenty_train.target_names[loaded_model.predict([file])[0]]))`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use pickle to save the model, you save only the model itself, but not the data, which was used for training. So if you want to load data with pickle, you need to save in separately. For example:

```
data = {'train': X_train, 'target': y_train}
with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
X_train = data['train']
y_train = data['target']
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but How do i achieve the same?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for the response